# How to generate future time in milliseconds in Jmeter using timeshift function

Tags: jmeter

How to generate future time in milliseconds in Jmeter using time shift function. As I need to post a request having end time of tomorrow in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the blog here for timeShift function details:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift

To create the future timestamp in the specified format, please refer the below code and snapshot.

```
${__timeShift(dd-MM-y-HH-mm-ss-ms,,P1DT3H4M,,)}
```

[image: Function Helper]

Comment: I need to get future time in milliseconds but the above is giving in dd-MM-YYYY format